# Bootstrap popover displayed on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a data-binded list with one of the columns displaying a popover:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: tehTab()">
   <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.Category"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: $data.Name"></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn" onclick="getInfo(this.id)" data-bind="attr: { id: $data.Id}, text: $data.Value" style="border:none; background-color:white"></button></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

and the **getInfo** function:

```
function getInfo(click) {
    $('#' + click).popover({
        content: 'Dana' + Math.random(),
        html: true
    });
}
```

My only problem is that the popover appears on the second click, but I don't know why. Is there something I need to add?

Comment: Are there any messages in the developer console?

Comment: No, no error message or things like that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the reason :) On the first click my popover is being initialized and on the second one is displayed. The solution for it was:

```
function getInfo(click) {
    $('#' + click).popover({
        content: 'Dana',
        html: true
    });

    $('#' + click).popover("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue, when initializing different way. The solution for me was to initialize it like:

```
$(document).on("page:load ready", function(){
  $('body').popover({selector: '.my-popover-class', trigger: 'click'});
})
```

Further options for `popover()` are [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_popover.asp).